# How can I undo latest commit and retain changes?

Tags: git

I have several commits already and I need to undo the latest one but to have changes I made in it in place. Please advice how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit

Comment: Why? Do you need to change that commit (adding/removing changes to it)?

Comment: I need to change comment and add some other files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Note that you should only rewind HEAD if it's not pushed yet.

---

**edit** In response to your comment on the original question:

If you only want to edit the most recent commit, Git has a neat feature `commit --amend`. Simply use `git add`/`git rm`/`git checkout` until your index is in the state you want it to be (new changes added, some changes thrown away, files removed, …). Then use `git commit --amend`, it will pop up vi (or whatever you have configured in `core.editor`) with your last commit's commit message for you to edit.

Note, that when I say ›edit the most recent commit‹, Git actually creates a new commit. So don't do it, when the commit was already pulled from other people (i.e. pushed to your public repository)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update *the most recent commit*, then amending this commit would do the job:

```
<do the changes you want to>
git add <missing files>
git add <changed files>
git commit --amend
```

That's it.

If you need to change comment and add some other files *to previous commit*, I suggest you do [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) instead.

```
<do the changes you want to>
git add <missing files>
git commit -a
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

In editor that pops up you'll see something like

```
pick <SHA1> Commit that you wanted to change
pick <SHA2> Next commit that you seem to try to rollback in your question
pick <SHA3> Just committed fixes to SHA1
```

Change it to be

```
pick <SHA1> Commit that you wanted to change
f <SHA3> Just committed fixes to SHA1
pick <SHA2> Next commit that you seem to try to rollback in your question
```

('f' means 'fixup' -- squash SHA1 ans SHA3 and discard commit message of SHA3 one)

Save changes, quit editor. You are done.

That should never be done for commits you've already pushed upstream.

Comment: What is the difference between `previous` and `most recent` commit? I see no difference.

Comment: The most recent commit is the current one (ie the head of your branch). The previous commit is the parent of the current one.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for ambiguity here. In my terminology "the most recent" was `HEAD`, "the previous one" was `HEAD^`.